# Adding an element to a ManyToManyField in Django not saved?

Tags: python, django, django-models, manytomanyfield

While I was making one of my first projects on Django, I had to create two models. One of them, `Image`, has a field `tags` which is a `ManyToManyField` referring to the other model, `Tag`. I wanted to add elements to the `tags` field with a `post_save` signal. No problem occur during this process (in particular, the elements I want to add exist), but at the end no element is added.

Here is a **snipplet** of the `models.py` I've written so far :

```py
# (Importing the modules ...)

class Image(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", related_name="images", blank=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

@receiver(post_save, sender=Image)
def create_tags(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print(f"Before : {instance.tags.all()}")
        tag = Tag.objects.get(name="mytag")
        instance.tags.add(tag)
        instance.save()
        print(f"After : {instance.tags.all()}")
```

When I add an element through the admin panel, the following is printed :

```
Before : <QuerySet []>
After : <QuerySet [<Tag: mytag>]>
```

But if I check the freshly added element, no tag is selected.

Could you please help me figuring out what I am doing wrong ? Thanks in advance and have a nice day !

---

**EDIT** : I have added the following at the end of `create_tags`:

```py
print(f"Instances with tag 'mytag' : {Tag.objects.get(name='mytag').images.all()}")
```

Every time I add an element, this only displays the element I am currently adding. Would this mean that the modification is not carried out of `create_tags` ?

---

**EDIT 2** : I finally figured out where the problem was. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75956195/21166833).

Comment: based on that code, you're simply grabbing the first Tag instance from the database and adding it to the tags field. replace `tag = Tag.objects.first()` with `tag = Tag.objects.get(name="mytag")  # Replace "myfirsttag" with the name of the tag you want to add`

Comment: Oh here adding the first tag was just as an example. In reality the code is more complex than that, but for readability I tried to shorten the code to the essential part. I've edited my original post to avoid this confusion !

Comment: remove `instance.save()` and try again

Comment: Still not working :( I also added `print(f"Instances with tag 'mytag' : {Tag.objects.get(name='mytag').images.all()}")` at the end of the `create_tags` function to see what is happening : every time I add an element to `Image`, this print only displays the current element I am adding, which seems to say that the modification is not carried out of this `create_tags` function ?

Comment: it's possible that the tags field is being cleared by another signal receiver after your c_t function is executed. This explains why the tag isnt being added to the Image instance. You can specify the dispatch_uid argument when connecting the receiver. This will give your receiver a unique identifier and ensure that it is only connected once. `@receiver(post_save, sender=Image, dispatch_uid="add_tag_to_image")`. Make sure to also add dispatch_uid to the @receiver decorator for your create_tags function.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. Sadly this doesn't work neither. Moreover, I did not define any other reciever that could have interfered with it. Nevertheless, thanks for having taught me something about receivers :)

Comment: try using `m2m_changed` signal. send me a dm and we can solve this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the problem ! At least for `ManyToManyField`, tt turns out that adding an element should be done using a transaction. For this, one has to import `from django.db import transaction`. Then, instead of just writing `instance.tags.add(tag)`, this operation should be enveloped as follows :

```py
def add_tag():
    instance.tags.add(tag)
transaction.on_commit(add_tag)
```

If someone encounters the same problem, I hope this might help :)